# How can I subscribe to redux state changes from a background script?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, redux

I am trying to build a chrome extension in which users can record their voice and camera. This extension currently uses redux, with the help of the `react-chrome-redux` module, to store the state so that it is accessible in places like the background scripts.

However, I can't seem to figure out how it will work. My file tree essentially looks like this:

```
▾ requestAccess/  
  ¦ request.html  
  ¦ request.js                                 
▾ event/                        
  ▸ src/ 
  ¦ captureMedia.js                                       
▾ popup/                        
  ▸ src/                        
  ¦ ¦ index.html
  ¦ ¦ index.js
  ¦ ¦ Popup.jsx
▾ store/                        
  ▾ src/                        
  ¦ ▾ reducers/                 
  ¦ ¦ ¦ store.js                
  ¦ ¦ ¦ recordingReducer.js
```

I would like the `event/src/captureMedia.js` file to listen to the state changes in the redux store, and once the state changes from `recording: false` to `recording: true`, it should be able to execute the code to start recording.

My code structure is very similar to [this example](https://github.com/tshaddix/react-chrome-redux-examples/tree/master/clicker-key) from `react-chrome-redux'.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like the `event/src/captureMedia.js` file to listen to the state
>   changes in the redux store, and once the state changes from `recording:
>   false` to `recording: true`, it should be able to execute the code to
>   start recording.

A file can't listen for store changes. A component can by using the [`connect()`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) hoc from `react-redux`. If you did setup your store as described in [Getting Started](https://github.com/tshaddix/react-chrome-redux/wiki/Getting-Started) there should be no additional setup required to listen to store changes:

## 1. Add the Proxy Store to a UI Component, such as a popup

**popover.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {Store} from 'react-chrome-redux';

import TodoApp from './TodoApp';

const store = new Store({
  portName: 'MY_APP' // communication port name
});

// The store implements the same interface as Redux's store
// so you can use tools like `react-redux` no problem!
render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <TodoApp/>
  </Provider>
  , document.getElementById('app'));
```

## 2. Wrap your Redux store in the background page with wrapStore()

**background.js**

```
import {wrapStore} from 'react-chrome-redux';

const store; // a normal Redux store

wrapStore(store, {portName: 'MY_APP'}); // make sure portName matches
```

That's it! The dispatches called from UI component will find their way to the background page no problem. The new state from your background page will make sure to find its way back to the UI components.

## 3. Connect your component as usual

**TodoApp.js**

```
const TodoApp = ({todos}) => (
    <ul>
        {todos.map(todo => <li key={todo.id}>{todo.title}</li>)}
    </ul>
);

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { todos: state.todos }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actionCreators)(TodoApp);
```

Comment: So does wrapStore() provide a state variable? Unfortunately they don't have documentation for any of these methods.